# How to query CSV using pure spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, command-line-interface

I hope to get output from spark-sql CLI. But the data is in CSV which is separated by "\t". Is there any way to do this using pure sql?

cmd like: `` spark-sql -e 'select * from csv.`xxx` where xxx=xxx' ``

The only way is to create a temp view first and then query the view?

Answer (score 0):

you can create table for existing data with all options, like, this:

```sql
create table if not exists table_name
using csv
OPTIONS (header "true", inferSchema "true", path ".....csv");
```

and the query it in next calls.  Or you can have this statement in the `.sql` file, and then provide file name via `-i` option to be performed before your `select` query.

Answer (score 0):

This command works using delimiter "t" and creating a table

```
spark-sql -e 'create table if not exists benchmark_eraseme
using csv 
OPTIONS (header "true", delimiter "\t", path "/home/ec2-user/demo/customer_benchmark.csv"); 
select * from benchmark_eraseme;'
```

File:

```
cat ~/demo/customer_benchmark.csv
id_customer     description
49      client_1
8       Benchmark Gold
6       Benchmark Silver
7       Benchmark Regular
```

Output:

```
Time taken: 8.467 seconds
49      client_1
8       Benchmark Gold
6       Benchmark Silver
7       Benchmark Regular
Time taken: 0.548 seconds, Fetched 4 row(s)
```

I tried using a temporary view but at least in Spark 3.2.1 version it is not possible to create temporary views from CSV file.